# How to pass the string in Morris Donut value

Tags: javascript, php, morris.js

How to pass the string in morris donut under data array value. i have a morris donut like this [Donut 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ckOL.png) And this is my code. I want like this Donut. [Donut 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppekt.png)

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: [
    <?php foreach ($pay as $r_pay): ?>
      {label: 'Level Name: <?= $r_pay['level_id']; ?>',value: '<?=$r_pay['total']; ?>'},
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Morris Documentation](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/donuts.html) it indicates that along with `element` and `data` one may also add `formatter` which

> will translate a y-value into a label for the centre of the donut.

Here is an example:

```
Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
    data: [
      {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
      {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
      {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
    ],
  formatter: function (y, data) { return 'Due Amount: ' + y }
});
```

Which produces this:

[image]